# Why SendInput windows API call fails when mouse hovers on some applications like Kaspersky Anti-virus tool?

Tags: winapi

My application is service-based which is installed into Virtual machine(VM) . This service(SYSTEM a/c) creates another process(SYSTEM a/c) which is used to handle mouse operations for multi-monitor support of VM guest.

Installed Kaspersky Anti-virus tool into VM. Kaspersky service(SYSTEM a/c) creates process(to handle UI) with logged-on user and 'Medium' integrity level.

When I do mouse hovers on kaspersky tool, no mouse operation(mouse move, mouse click) works. Initially thought it could be UIPI issue and checked integrity levels of both processes.

Don't understand why SendInput Windows API fails even my application has higher integrity level than Kaspersky tool?

Comment: Suppose it was you that wrote an anti-virus product and you need to make it Really Secure.  Would you allow other apps to poke keystrokes and mouse clicks into your user interface?

Answer (score 1):

I think this kind of software block this functions from kernel mode, for example hook NtUserSendInput function. But this is only my opinion. :-)